# plot gebco data in python basemap

Tags: python, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

I have downloaded some gebco bathymetry data as a netCDF file. I would like to plot it with python-basemap. I have tried,

```
import netCDF4
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


# Load data
dataset = netCDF4.Dataset('/home/david/Desktop/GEBCO/gebco_08_-30_45_5_65.nc')

# Extract variables
x = dataset.variables['x_range']
y = dataset.variables['y_range']
spacing = dataset.variables['spacing']

# Data limits
nx = (x[-1]-x[0])/spacing[0]   # num pts in x-dir
ny = (y[-1]-y[0])/spacing[1]   # num pts in y-dir

# Reshape data
zz = dataset.variables['z']
Z = zz[:].reshape(ny, nx)



# setup basemap.
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-30,llcrnrlat=45.0,urcrnrlon=5.0,urcrnrlat=65.0,
            resolution='i',projection='stere',lon_0=-15.0,lat_0=55.0)


# Set up grid
lons, lats = m.makegrid(nx, ny)
x, y = m(lons, lats)

m.contourf(x, y, flipud(Z))
m.fillcontinents(color='grey')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(10,70,10), labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-80, 5, 10), labels=[0,0,0,1])
```

this gives the figure below, clearly not correct. The problem stems from how the areas are defined. For basemap area is defined by lower left corner lat,lon and upper right corner lat, lon. But the gebco data takes a maximum and minimum lon/lat defined along a center line.
Anyone have any experience with gebco data or see a solution??

thanks
D
[image: map]

Comment: What's the motivation for creating `X` and `Y` (btw you do it twice) or for `Z=zz[:].reshape(shape(X))`? You also haven't defined `nx` or `ny` in the code provided. What do they represent?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit unclear. Code has been updated. zz is reshaped as it is a single column vector.

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? If they are longitude and latitude arrays respectively, there is no need to use `makegrid` with `nx` and `ny`; just do `x,y = m(*np.meshgrid(x, y))`. Perhaps that also fixes the problem?

Comment: x and y contain the max and min values for lon and lat, spacing is the grid step size. I create the lon lat arrays from them. Using the arrays as you suggest instead of makegrid works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

so just for the record, here's the answer that works, using the comments above:

```
import netCDF4
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

# Load data
dataset = netCDF4.Dataset('/usgs/data1/rsignell/bathy/gebco_08_-30_-45_5_65.nc')

# Extract variables
x = dataset.variables['x_range']
y = dataset.variables['y_range']
spacing = dataset.variables['spacing']

# Compute Lat/Lon
nx = (x[-1]-x[0])/spacing[0]   # num pts in x-dir
ny = (y[-1]-y[0])/spacing[1]   # num pts in y-dir

lon = np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],nx)
lat = np.linspace(y[0],y[-1],ny)

# Reshape data
zz = dataset.variables['z']
Z = zz[:].reshape(ny, nx)

# setup basemap.
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-30,llcrnrlat=45.0,urcrnrlon=5.0,urcrnrlat=65.0,
            resolution='i',projection='stere',lon_0=-15.0,lat_0=55.0)

x,y = m(*np.meshgrid(lon,lat))

m.contourf(x, y, flipud(Z));
m.fillcontinents(color='grey');
m.drawparallels(np.arange(10,70,10), labels=[1,0,0,0]);
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-80, 5, 10), labels=[0,0,0,1]);
```

which produces this plot.[image]