# Bathymetry maps in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, colormap

After searching I've still not been able to locate whether it is possible to create bathymetry maps using python. I can't seem to find this feature with Basemap, so would anyone have any clue as to how I can go about doing this, if possible?

Comment: Matplotlib is what you need.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116319/plotting-elevation-maps-and-shaded-relief-images-from-latitude-longitude-and-e

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm looking for a map, not plots as such. It doesn't have to be highly accurate as it's more for visual effects only. There are standard maps i.e. bluemarble in Basemap which are pretty aesthetic, but the sea depths in these maps are not color coded i.e. one can't tell what depth range the sea bed is.

Comment: You could use full GEBCO bathymetry (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22205358/1328439). See also this tutorial on subsetting (https://publicwiki.deltares.nl/display/OET/OPeNDAP+subsetting+with+python)

Answer (score 1):

As iFlo mentioned on the comments, you could do it with Matplotlib. I came across these examples:

- https://oceanpython.org/2013/03/21/bathymetry-topography-srtm30/
- http://iuryt.github.io/tutorial/Como_fazer_um_mapa02.html